# Is my proof for this correct? Prove $2^{n+1} > n^{2}$ for any positive integer n.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, solution-verification

Claim: $2^{n+1} >n^{2}$ for any positive integer n.

My proof:

$n = 1 \longrightarrow$

$2^{1+1} > 1^{2} \iff 4 > 1$

Check.

$n=2\longrightarrow$

$2^{2+1} > 2^{2} \iff 8 > 4$

Check.

Induction hypothesis: The claim is true for some positive integer $k$.

Inductive step:

$2^{k+1} > k^2$ (inductive hypothesis)

$2^{k+1} > k^2\ge k\implies 2^{k+1} > k\implies 2^{(k+1)+1} > (k+1)$, because $(k+1)$ is just some positive integer.

This implies that $2^{(k+1) + 1} > (k+1)^{2}$.

So we are done.

**Is my proof sound?**

Comment: I don't understand your proof at all .  You aren't trying to show that $2^{k+1}>k$, you are tying to show that it is $>k^2$.  But even if you were trying to show that it was $>k$ just saying "$(k+1)$ is some positive integer" isn't even an argument.

Comment: in the step after the inductive hypothesis, should you not then be incrementing $k$ by $1$ and showing that $2^{k+2} > (k+1)^2$?

Comment: How does $2^{(k+1)+1} > (k+1)$ imply $2^{(k+1)+1 }> (k+1)^2$? If you set $a = 2^{(k+1)+1}$ and $b = (k+1)$ then your argument becomes "$a > b \implies a > b^2$", which is false (take $a = 3$ and $b = 2$).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the final step you make... I think your proof is incorrect.

I do the exercise in this way:

$k=1$ check;

$k=2$ check.

Now I should say that if $2^{k+1}>k^2$ then $2^{k+2}>(k+1)^2$ (where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k>1$) .

Firstly observe that if $k>1$ you have that $2k+1<2^{k+1}$

(you can try this by induction:
It holds for $k=2$ and if $2k+1<2^{k+1}$ with $k>1$ so $2(k+1)+1<2^{k+1}+2\leqslant 2^{k+1}+2^{k+1}=2^{k+2}$).

Now if $2^{k+1}>k^2$, then $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1< 2^{k+1}+2^{k+1}=2^{k+2}$. So you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, prove that $k^2>2k+1$ for sufficiently large $k$. It works for $k\ge 3$.  I wont prove it.

Second, prove the base case of your hypothesis for $k=3$.  We have $2^{3+1} = 16 > 9 = 3^2.$

Third, the inductive step. Assume $2^{k+1} > k^2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, $2^{(k+1)+1} = 2\cdot 2^{k+1}> 2\cdot k^2=k^2+k^2>k^2+2k+1 = (k+1)^2$.

Then you can show this relationship works for $k=0,1,2$ as well.